# React Native app Cannot Fetch data from Firestore using Api NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is React native expo mobile app. I'm using NodeJs Server to get data from Firestore. Postman api fetch data properly.
Cannot fetch data from react native mobile app.

**Postman Output**

```
"customer": [
        {
            "phone":12345,
            "username": "customer1",
        },
]
```

**Redux action.js**

```
import { SET_CUSTOMERS } from "../types";
import { create } from "axios";
import { auth } from "../../firebase";

const baseURL = "https://...../api/";

const API = create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 60000,
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
});

export const getCustomers = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
      console.log("token ", token); //Working Well

      const response = API({
        url: "customers",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

      console.log(response); //NOT Working

      dispatch({ type: SET_CUSTOMERS, payload: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
};
```

**Redux reducer.js**

```
import { SET_CUSTOMERS } from "../types";

const initialState = {
  customers: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CUSTOMERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        customers: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getCustomers } from "../store/actions/data";

const UserProfileView = (props) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const customers = useSelector((state) => state.data.customers);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const loadCustomers = useCallback(async () => {
    setError(null);
    try {
      await dispatch(getCustomers());
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  }, [dispatch, setError]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCustomers;
  }, [loadCustomers]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Customer Details</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Expected Output `payload: response.data` pass response.data array**

```
export const getCustomers = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
      console.log("token ", token); //Working Well

      const response = API({
        url: "customers",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

      console.log(response); //NOT Working

      dispatch({ type: SET_CUSTOMERS, payload: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Not familiar with the syntax but I am quite sure the API call should return promise so you should add 'await'.

Comment: @D10S As a suggestion where should I add `await` ? Thank you..

Comment: const response = await API({...

Comment: @D10S Thank you... Working Fetching Data Well... <3 :)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it helped.